# Variable Issues with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, console

The problem is I don't know why the Python console shows so many variables on the bottom right and not just the ones in the code. Is it because of the directory?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can get dict of all variables using `globals()` function

global variables is **name**, **doc**, **file**, **loader** and other

name of file, his directory and others

Comment: I don't really understand your answer,  is there any way to just show the variables in the code?

Comment: i use pycharm comunity edition and it gives me this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/788349108678688792/943591127309754418/unknown.png